# Error: volttron.platform.web INFO: Web server not started

Tags: volttron

I am having a hard time creating my first example listener agent on the Volttron platform. This is the error I am getting when I enter the (tail volttron.log) command after creating and starting the agent:

> 2017-01-13 13:12:56,664 (listeneragent-3.2 16153)
>   volttron.platform.vip.agent.core ERROR: No response to hello message
>   after 10 seconds.
>
> 2017-01-13 13:12:56,664 (listeneragent-3.2 16153)
>   volttron.platform.vip.agent.core ERROR: A common reason for this is a
>   conflicting VIP IDENTITY.
>
> 2017-01-13 13:12:56,664 (listeneragent-3.2 16153)
>   volttron.platform.vip.agent.core ERROR: Shutting down agent.
>
> 2017-01-13 13:12:56,664 (listeneragent-3.2 16153)
>   volttron.platform.vip.agent.core ERROR: Possible conflicting identity
>   is: platform.listener }
>
> **When I activate the Volttron platform and just run the (tail volttron.log) command without creating any agents, I get this message
>   in the terminal :-**
>
> { 2017-01-13 13:22:06,276 () volttron.platform.vip.agent.core DEBUG:
>   Running onstart methods.
>
> 2017-01-13 13:22:06,277 () volttron.platform.vip.agent.core INFO:
>   Connected to platform: router: ce01039f-9fc1-4395-b294-0c008f43aa8b
>   version: 1.0 identity: pubsub
>
> 2017-01-13 13:22:06,277 () volttron.platform.vip.agent.core DEBUG:
>   Running onstart methods.
>
> 2017-01-13 13:22:06,278 () volttron.platform.vip.agent.core INFO:
>   Connected to platform: router: ce01039f-9fc1-4395-b294-0c008f43aa8b
>   version: 1.0 identity: pubsub.compat
>
> 2017-01-13 13:22:06,278 () volttron.platform.vip.agent.core DEBUG:
>   Running onstart methods.
>
> 2017-01-13 13:22:06,279 () volttron.platform.vip.agent.core INFO:
>   Connected to platform: router: ce01039f-9fc1-4395-b294-0c008f43aa8b
>   version: 1.0 identity: master.web
>
> 2017-01-13 13:22:06,279 () volttron.platform.vip.agent.core DEBUG:
>   Running onstart methods.
>
> 2017-01-13 13:22:06,279 () volttron.platform.main INFO: loading
>   protected-topics file /home/mint/.volttron/protected_topics.json
>
> 2017-01-13 13:22:06,279 () volttron.platform.main INFO:
>   protected-topics file /home/mint/.volttron/protected_topics.json
>   loaded
>
> 2017-01-13 13:22:06,279 () **volttron.platform.web INFO: Web server
>   not started.** }

Any idea what's causing this error: `INFO: Web server not started.` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(We actually solved this in an over the phone conversation, I'm not psychic)

This is what happens when you attempt to run VOLTTRON on the Mint OS Live CD and not from an installed copy of Mint.

You will also see authentication errors in the log when Agents try to start up.

In the VM double click on the "Install Linux Mint" icon on the desktop and follow the prompts. Once Mint is installed on the VM restart the VM and proceed with the normal installation instructions.