# volttron.platform.vip.agent.core ERROR: No response to hello message after 10 seconds

Tags: volttron

I am removing some volttron agents and I keep running into errors. It is usually the case when I do "vctl status" or try to remove or stop some already installed agents. I also encounter it when shutting down so that I have to manually enter the .volttron directory and remove the keystore files, and delete all the directories for agents.

I see an almost similar question was asked here: [volttron.platform.vip.agent.core ERROR: Possible conflicting identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013280/volttron-platform-vip-agent-core-error-possible-conflicting-identity). But I go through the installation process to install my agents and don't run from Eclipse at all.

```py
python scripts/install-agent.py -s Node611/PredAgent/ -c Node611/PredAgent/config -t p11
```

These are the errors:

> 2019-08-06 11:00:12,070 () volttron.platform.vip.agent.core ERROR: No response to hello message after 10 seconds.
>   2019-08-06 11:00:12,070 () volttron.platform.vip.agent.core ERROR: A common reason for this is a conflicting VIP IDENTITY.
>   2019-08-06 11:00:12,070 () volttron.platform.vip.agent.core ERROR: Another common reason is not having an auth entry onthe target instance.
>   2019-08-06 11:00:12,071 () volttron.platform.vip.agent.core ERROR: Shutting down agent.
>   2019-08-06 11:00:12,071 () volttron.platform.vip.agent.core ERROR: Possible conflicting identity is: control.connection
>   remove: operation timed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there other warning messages in the log before this error? Do you see any authentication errors/warnings before this error message? You would have to explicitly authorize an agent to access VOLTTRON platform. You can either do a 'vctl auth add' for a single agent or in case development or testing environment allow access to all agents by setting credentials=/.*/ when doing 'vctl auth add'

Another possible reason for this could be connection issues with broker. Are you using ZMQ or RabbitMQ message bus? If using RabbitMQ could you check the rabbitmq log to see if there are any errors?

Comment: Hello Chandrika, I appreciate your efforts here. I don't see any errors before these specific ones. Also, I never do vctl auth add before using those vctl commands. I'm running all agents on the same virtual machine in the same volttron instance. Again, I'm using ZMQ.

Strangely, I haven't encountered the problem after I fixed the problem in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57381055/volttron-enters-what-seems-like-an-almost-endless-loop